# angular.js show/hide slide up

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have two Bootstrap panels, one placed on top of the other. I am using ng-show/ng-hide to hide the top panel. Then the top panel hides, I would like the bottom panel to slide up slowly instead of simply jumping up.

I have an example here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/rfpmUWC24J4PLwqfqczM

Click on any of the company names and for the top panel to disappear.

Comment: Instead of using ng-hide/ng-show write a directive.

Comment: Use ng-animate its a piece of cake to animate showing and hiding!

Comment: I can get it to fade out and in using ng-animate, the problem is that as soon as it fades out, the panel hides and the panel under jumps up. I would like that second panel to slide up, not jump up.